# How to hack into a Samsung Galaxy J5 with broken screen?

Tags: samsung, broken-screen, screen-sharing

The phone is Samsung Galaxy J5 and its screen is completely broken. USB debugging is not enabled either. I don't want to throw it out since everything else seems to be working fine. And I can't afford to buy a new one.

How do I hack into it and project its screen on a PC, so that I can use it like a webcam or mini server? It shouldn't be that hard since it's such an outdated OS. Should I inject some kind of code via USB or SD card?

Comment: flash modified boot with ro.debuggable=1, ro.adb.secure=0 in `default.prop` and connect [scrcpy](https://www.xda-developers.com/scrcpy-control-android-on-pc). there is also hands free root method [cf-auto-root](https://autoroot.chainfire.eu)